# How to iterate through a multiline string, and return a list with some parts of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a homework assignment, where I have to iterate through a multiline string and return a list with some parts of the string. I'm working with a text variable called TV, which holds a list of responsibilities at a workplace.

My code so far:

```
def findPersons(name)
    TV=     \
    '''
    My workplace
    Manager: Peter
    HR department: Casey
    IT: Alice
    Creative department: Casey
    Payroll department: Alice
    '''
    person=[]
    fra=0
    while True:
        result=TV.find(name,fra)
        if result==-1:break
        person.append(result)
        fra=result+1
    return person
```

Right now the code only returns the positions of the characters. I want the code to return a list of the different roles that the people in the workplace has.
i.e:

```
findPersons('Casey')
[HR department, Creative department]
```

Comment: Use `splitlines()` to split the string into lines, then loop over the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use `splitlines()` to split the string into lines, which you can loop over. Then split each line at the `:` character and check if the name matches

```
for line in TV.splitlines():
    if ':' in line:
        dept, employee = line.split(':')
        if employee.strip() == name:
            person.append(dept.strip())
```

Comment: You should probably `person.append(dept.strip())`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all lines using list comprehensions

You might want `line[:line.find(':')].strip()` as separate function for readability

```
def findPersons(name):
    TV=     \
    '''
    My workplace
    Manager: Peter
    HR department: Casey
    IT: Alice
    Creative department: Casey
    Payroll department: Alice
    '''
    return [line[:line.find(':')].strip() for line in TV.splitlines() if name in line]

findPersons('Casey')
```